# Dividing a number to equal chunks

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I'm trying to write a function that returns an array of equally chunked up dates and number of days pertaining to those dates. Should there be a remainder of those days they get appended to the array as follow.

Expected outcome:

```
[{
'startDate' : 20160719 //dates generated from momentjs
'numOfDays': 5
},{
'startDate' : 20160724
'numOfDays': 5
},{
'startDate' : 20160729
'numOfDays': 3
}]
```

Below is the function I've written in which you can pass in a start date (momentjs), the total number of days (daysToDisplay) and number of days to be divided by (numOfDays).

```
function buildQueue(startDate, numOfDays, daysToDisplay) {
    if (!startDate || !numOfDays || !daysToDisplay) {
        throw new Error('All params required!');
    }

    var num = numOfDays > daysToDisplay ? daysToDisplay : numOfDays;
    var div = Math.floor(daysToDisplay / num);
    var count = daysToDisplay;
    var rem = daysToDisplay % num;
    var lastItem;
    var i;
    var arr = [];

    for (i = 0; i <= daysToDisplay; i += num) {

        arr.push({
          startDate: moment(startDate, 'YYYYMMDD').add(i, 'days').format('YYYYMMDD'),
          numOfDays: numOfDays,
          count: i
        })

        if (rem === count) {
            break;
        }

        count -= num;

    }

    if (count > 0) {
        lastItem = arr[arr.length - 1];
        var leftover = daysToDisplay - lastItem.count;
        arr.push({
            startDate: moment(lastItem.startDate, 'YYYYMMDD').add(num, 'days').format('YYYYMMDD'),
            numOfDays: rem,
            count: leftover + lastItem.count
        });
    }

    return arr;

}
```

A working example is here (https://jsfiddle.net/zv5ghqpa/1/). The code appears to work in scenarios where daysToDisplay is dividable by more than 2.

When daysToDisplay is only dividable by one, we get an additional item in the returned array basically due to the zero index in the for loop. The expected outcome if I call buildQueue('20160719', 5, 8) should be:

```
[{
    'startDate': 20160719
    'numOfDays': 5
}, {
    'startDate': 20160724
    'numOfDays': 3    
}]
```

Instead its returning:

```
[{
    'startDate': 20160719
    'numOfDays': 5
},{
    'startDate': 20160724
    'numOfDays': 5
}, {
    'startDate': 20160729
    'numOfDays': 3    
}]
```

I hope i've given enough info... this is really doing my head in.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is code you're looking for:

```
function buildQueue(startDate, numOfDays, daysToDisplay) {

  if (!startDate || !numOfDays || !daysToDisplay) {
    throw new Error('All params required!');
  }

  var num = numOfDays > daysToDisplay ? daysToDisplay : numOfDays;
  var div = Math.floor(daysToDisplay / num);
  var count = daysToDisplay;
  var rem = daysToDisplay % num;
  var n = 0;
  var i;

  var arr = [];

  for (i = 0; i <= daysToDisplay; i += num) {

    arr.push({
      startDate: moment(startDate, 'YYYYMMDD').add(i, 'days').format('YYYYMMDD'),
      numOfDays: daysToDisplay % num,
      count: i
    })

    console.log(rem + ' ' + count);

    if (rem === count) {
      count = 0;
      break;
    }

    count -= num;

  }

  if (count > 0) {
    var leftover = daysToDisplay - arr[arr.length - 1].count;
    arr.push({
      startDate: moment(arr[arr.length - 1].startDate, 'YYYYMMDD').add(num, 'days').format('YYYYMMDD'),
      numOfDays: daysToDisplay % num,
      count: leftover + arr[arr.length - 1].count
    });
  }

  return arr;

}

//console.log(buildQueue(moment(), 80, 100));
console.log(buildQueue(moment(), 5, 8));
//console.log(buildQueue(moment(), 15, 100));
//console.log(buildQueue(moment(), 30, 100));
//console.log(buildQueue(moment(), 45, 100));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the 'Expected outcome' was correct before you edited the question.  I also note the sample code produced a `count` property that you don't want in the output.

Perhaps this code does what you want?

```
function buildQueue(startDate, numOfDays, daysToDisplay) {
    var arr = []
    while (daysToDisplay > 0) {
        arr.push({
            startDate: moment(startDate, 'YYYYMMDD')
                       .add(numOfDays * arr.length, 'days')
                       .format('YYYYMMDD'),
            numDays: Math.min(numOfDays, daysToDisplay)
        })
        daysToDisplay -= numOfDays
    }
    return arr
}
```